# Why one SQS message doesn't get deleted while others do?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I came across this question in my AWS study:

> You create an SQS queue and decide to test it out by creating a simple
>   application which looks for messages in the queue. When a message is
>   retrieved, the application is supposed to delete the message. You
>   create three test messages in your SQS queue and discover that
>   messages 1 and 3 are quickly deleted but message 2 remains in the
>   queue. What is a possible cause for this behavior? Choose the 2
>   correct answers

```
Options:
A.  The order that messages are received in is not guaranteed in SQS
B.  Message 2 uses JSON formatting
C.  You failed to set the correct permissions on message 2
D.  Your application is using short polling
```

Correct Answer:

```
A. The order that messages are received in is not guaranteed in SQS
D. Your application is using short polling
```

Why A is considered as one the answer here? I understand A is correct from the SQS feature definition, however, it does not explain to the issue in this question, right? Why it is not the permission issue?

Anything I am missing?

Thank you.

Comment: I think it's an example of a poorly-written question. It might simply be saying that the message could still be "in-flight" because the messages weren't necessarily processed in-order.

Comment: Thanks, would you please comment on option C?

Comment: Individual messages do not have permissions. Only the queue, or users accessing the queue, have permissions.

Comment: Thank you, in this case, since user has no problem with other messages, that confirmed there is no permission issue on the queue, meaning C can be excluded, right? Please rephrase your reply as "answer" and I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a justification for `A` & `D` is:

- Various workers might be pulling messages from the queue
- Given that it is not a FIFO queue, then message order is not guaranteed (`A`)
- Short-polling will not necessarily check every 'server', it will simply return a message (`D`)
- Message 2 simply hasn't been processed yet

Frankly, I don't think that `D` is so relevant, because Long Polling returns as soon as it gets a message and it simply means that no worker has requested the message yet.

`B` is irrelevant because message content has no impact on retrieval.

`C` is incorrect because there are no permissions on individual messages. Only the queue, or users accessing the queue, have permissions.